# How to call onActivityResult() from inside Preference Fragment?

Tags: java, android

I don't know if this is already answered. Say I call startActivityForResult() from inside a Preference Fragment and then also use onActivityResult() inside this Preference Fragment:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.my_preferences, rootKey);
            ...

            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); //should this line be commented?
            if (requestCode == 1)
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "peepeepoopoo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }

    }

}
```

Should `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` be called in this case?

Comment: i don't think it needs to be commented , it should work fine this way

Comment: Is there any possible difference?

Comment: i use it this way all time and it works fine , you can try and see how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be kept as it is without commenting out:

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

The code inside the super method is :

> ```
> @Override
> public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>
>     mPreferenceManager.dispatchActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
> }
> ```

So, yes, there is a difference.

Comment: But what is the difference?

Comment: Also what is the purpose of dispatchActivityResult()?

Comment: If you want to listen to onActivityResult event from a PreferenceManager object, you can register an  OnActivityResultListener in that object. When dispatchActivityResult() is invoke, OnActivityResultListener.onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) will also get invoked.